# Making line charts y-axis work?

Tags: javascript, charts, raphael, prototypejs, linechart

I'm implementing [this](http://joedesigns.com/labs/Beautiful-Analytics-Chart/) charting solution and I'm a little stuck. If I have to line charts in the same graph, as in the first example in the link, but there seems to be a problem with the y-axis. It doesn't show the right ratio between the first and second line chart. See the two images below:

[image]

[image]
Does anybody have an idea of how to solve this?!

Thanx!

P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand your problem: the scale of each of the lines on the graph are independent, and the raphael line graph js file is looping through the table data and setting each line's max according to its max value. My recommendation to anyone thinking of using raphaeljs for graphing purposes is to use [Graphael](http://g.raphaeljs.com/) instead.

If you REALLY want to fix it, change line 366 of the raphael_linechart in the example files to

```
max = this.max,
```

Then add a function that gets the data, and changes the this.max variable to the max value of all the data:

```
changeMaxValue: function(id) {
    var table = helpers.loadTableData(id);
    var max = Math.max.apply(Math, table.data);
    if(max > this.max) {
        this.max = max;
    }
},
```

Pass the id of each table data piece before you actually graph the lines. I didn't test this, so you will have to work out the kinks.